# Changing where an object is on a GridBagLayout in Java

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am working on a project where I have a requirement that when a button is clicked, an object that is in a GridBagLayer moves to a different spot.  Here is my code so far:

```
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class main extends JFrame{
    private JButton button,littlebutton;
    private JLabel holdred1,holdred2;
    private ImageIcon red1,red2;

public main(){
//sets the layout
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
//sets the button
button = new JButton("Button");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
add(button,c);
//sets the image
red1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/redtile.png"));
red2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/redtile.png"));
//puts it in the JLabel
holdred1 = new JLabel(red1);
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
add(holdred1, c);
holdred2 = new JLabel(red2);
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
add(holdred2, c);
littlebutton = new JButton("Click Me");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
add(littlebutton,c);

event e = new event();
littlebutton.addActionListener(e);
}

public class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //code goes here


    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    //displaying the window
    main gui = new main();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(575,575);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Change Spot");
}
}
```

I don't have much experience with Grid Bag Layouts so I have no clue how to do this, Thanks in advance!

The question is how can I make the button change it's  gridx to 1

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

In `GridBagConstraints` you specify what position you want the element to take in the grid. You already have done that, in this portion of code

```
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
add(holdred1, c);
holdred2 = new JLabel(red2);
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
add(holdred2, c);
littlebutton = new JButton("Click Me");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
```

But you're telling the layout to place multiple components in the same grid using `c.gridx = 0, c.gridy = 0`. Every component should have its own cell space so they don't overlap.

I edited your code:

```
 setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
//sets the button
            button = new JButton("Button");
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 2;
            add(button, c);
//sets the image
//            red1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/redtile.png"));
//            red2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/redtile.png"));
//puts it in the JLabel
            holdred1 = new JLabel("Red1");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            add(holdred1, c);
            holdred2 = new JLabel("Red2");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 2;
            add(holdred2, c);
            littlebutton = new JButton("Click Me");
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 1;
            add(littlebutton, c);

            event e = new event();
            littlebutton.addActionListener(e);
```

I assume that you wanted the labels to be on top of the buttons, so I place they on a side so you could practice it.

Another easy tips, if you want a component to take more than a cell in the table you have to use `c.weightx = someValue, c.weighty = someValue`.

Take a look: [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Comment: Thanks for trying @Yayotrón but I wanted it to have when you clicked the little button that the other button would move to the other square, I am trying to make a game where this is necessary, If you could figure this out I would appreciate is greatly.

Comment: @SuperCoder oooh. I'm very sorry I read wrong your question. I'll update my answer tomorrow, I'm away from my computer now.